# How do I add a Maven dependency in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependency-management

I don't know how to use Maven at all.  I've been developing for a couple years with Eclipse and haven't yet needed to know about it.  However, now I'm [looking at some docs](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/json.html) that suggest I do the following:

*"To include it within your project, just add this maven dependency to your build."*

```
<repository>
   <id>jboss</id>
   <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
</repository>

   ...
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
   <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

How do I do this with my Eclipse project?

Please assume I know nothing about Maven. I just figured out it might be installed on my computer by typing `mvn` on the command line, but that's seriously the extent of my knowledge.  I would be happy to continue knowing nothing about Maven if there is an equivalent, non-Maven way of following these instructions with Eclipse.

Comment: Have you read the Maven Starting Guide: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html

Comment: The non-Maven equivalent: Find all libraries that you need and add them to your project's build path (lib directory). "All libraries that you need" = resteasy-jackson-provider-1.1.GA.jar (2.3.0 is the current version...) plus all dependencies. "All dependencies" is what Maven does for you (in this situation). Looking it up they are jackson-core-asl, jackson-mapper-asl, jackson-jaxrs, jackson-xc. Learn a little Maven, it is absolutely worth the time.

Comment: You will find more information about Maven in the [Maven: The Complete Reference](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/) guide, and you should also consider to install the Eclipse [M2E](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Maven_Integration) plugin (previously known as m2eclipse).

Answer (score 226, accepted):

1. On the top menu bar, open **Window -> Show View -> Other**
2. In the Show View window, open **Maven -> Maven Repositories**

[image: Show View - Maven Repositories]

3. In the window that appears, right-click on **Global Repositories** and select **Go Into**
4. Right-click on "**central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)**" and select "**Rebuild Index**"

- **Note that it will take very long to complete the download!!!**

5. Once indexing is complete, Right-click on the project -> **Maven** -> **Add Dependency** and start typing the name of the project you want to import (such as "hibernate").

- The search results will auto-fill in the "Search Results" box below.

Comment: Legend has it, its still rebuilding the Index.

Comment: How long, roughly, does rebuilding these indexes take? Are we talking hours?

Comment: No, a few dozen minutes... it's been awhile... pun non-intended.

Comment: Word of advice: Eclipse (at leat the latest version as of May 2016) locks up ocmpletely while rebuilding the central Maven repository index. And the status has been stuck on "0%" for five minutes now. Don't make any plans.

Comment: Damn, I miss `<insert-name-of-previously-considered-to-be-worst-package-manager-ever-here>`

Comment: Wow, rebuilding index are you downloading the internet?

Comment: 6-8 Weeks later

Comment: I was fool enough to try and open the central folder... don't do that...

Comment: Note: If this was not a Maven project. Before step 5, you must right-click  project--> configure --> convert to Maven project.  Then step 5 will work.

Comment: VERY IMPORTANT: in order to have the Maven option, FIRST, you have to convert your project to a Maven Project. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362166/maven-option-is-not-found-in-eclipse

Comment: It took 45 minutes on my computer

Comment: When I did the rebuild, it took 5ish minutes, and said 0% the whole time (Eclipse EE, 2019-12)

Comment: Warning!! Its a trap!! :D

Comment: So Maven is helpful? I guess, if I had just copied those few libs I needed I would be done an hour ago. This is just ridiculous.

Comment: It feels indeed like a bad thing, I should have read the comments before run the stupid **Rebuild Index**! 
From pp who **come from Nuget or NPM**, you think that a package manager will be fast and out of the box, but seems to **not be the case with JAVA**

Comment: @OdedBreiner On Step 4, when I rebuild the index for the central repository, what should I expect to happen? I don't see any progress bar, and I don't see anything under Maven Repositories –> Global Repositories –> central.

Comment: Sorry @BrianSchack it's been almost 10 years...
I haven't used eclipse in a very long time.

Answer (score 31):

In fact when you open the pom.xml, you should see 5 tabs in the bottom. Click the pom.xml, and you can type whatever dependencies you want.

[image]

Comment: helped me out big time. didnt notice the 5 tabs before

Comment: Eclipse still doesn't recognize the dependencies from my pom.xml in my code. When I use IntelliJ it automatically downloads them and sets them up for code completion, doesn't eclipse do this?

Comment: If you already know the details of your dependency (group id, artifact id, version), then this is *much* faster than downloading the Internet just to include `my-favorite-library.jar` in your project.

Comment: @Cas  You may need to configure your project to us Maven. This seems to be the secret. As cliff2310 said:  "Note: If this was not a Maven project. Before step 5, you must right-click project--> configure --> convert to Maven project. Then step 5 will work. – cliff2310"

Answer (score 13):

You need to be using a Maven plugin for Eclipse in order to do this properly. The [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) plugin is built into the latest version of Eclipse, and does a decent if not perfect job of integrating Maven into the IDE. You will want to create your project as a 'Maven Project'. Alternatively you can import an existing Maven POM into your workspace to automatically create projects. Once you have your Maven project in the IDE, simply open up the POM and add your dependency to it.

Now, if you do not have a Maven plugin for Eclipse, you will need to get the jar(s) for the dependency in question and manually add them as classpath references to your project. This could get unpleasant as you will need not just the top level JAR, but all its dependencies as well.

Basically, I recommend you get a decent Maven plugin for Eclipse and let it handle the dependency management for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I already have a project with 1000 files in it - is there a way to *add* maven support, instead of starting from scratch?  I have the latest version of Eclipse

Comment: With the latest version of Eclipse and m2e you can right click on a regular Java project and enable Dependency Management for it. This will generate a pom.xml for the project, while leaving its structure intact.

Answer (score 12):

Open the pom.xml file.

under the `project` tag add `<dependencies>` as another tag, and google for the Maven dependencies. I used [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-core/1.0.0) to search.

So after getting the dependency create another tag `dependency` inside `<dependencies>` tag.

So ultimately it will look something like this.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>doc-examples</groupId>
  <artifactId>lambda-java-example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>lambda-java-example</name>
  <dependencies>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the similar issue and fixed by copying the missing Jar files in to .M2 Path,

For example: if you see the error message as `Missing artifact tws:axis-client:jar:8.7` then you have to download "axis-client-8.7.jar" file and paste the same in to below location will resolve the issue.

C:\Users\UsernameXXX.m2\repository\tws\axis-client\8.7(Paste axis-client-8.7.jar).

finally, right click on project->Maven->Update Project...Thats it.

happy coding.

Comment: Thanks!  This was not my specific problem but it helped me solve it.  In my case my jar was in the correct location but the path was slightly wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced same problem with maven dependencies, eg: unfortunetly your maven dependencies deleted from your buildpath,then you people get lot of exceptions,if you follow below process you can easily resolve this issue.

[image: Right click on project >> maven >> updateProject >> selectProject >> OK]