# How to add Maven dependencies to an Android project, in Eclipse, for someone with zero Maven experience?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

I've made a few Android apps, but every time I need a library, I'd either download the jar and include it in my `/libs` folder, or clone the repository and include it as an Android Library. However, many of the more robust libraries recommend using Maven, and considering that more and more people are using it, AND Gradle apparently uses it as well (another system I need to eventually adapt to), I feel like it's time I finally get on board. Unfortunately, most of the tutorials and questions regarding Maven that I've found seem to assume at least a basic working knowledge of the system. What I need is a "Baby's First Maven Tutorial," so to speak. Can anyone help?

For example, the networking library [Ion.](https://github.com/koush/ion) The Maven dependency block for it is as follows:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.koushikdutta.ion</groupId>
   <artifactId>ion</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

How would one incorporate this library into an existing Android project in Eclipse, via Maven, starting from the very beginning?

Comment: [Maven Complete Reference](http://www.sonatype.com/resources/books/maven-the-complete-reference/download) Chapter 14 of this book explain how to develop an android application with maven

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a "maven dependency" in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164893/how-do-i-add-a-maven-dependency-in-eclipse)

Comment: @Vic the answer on that question does not detail how to add maven to an **existing** project. It basically amounts to "get the plugin if it isn't already included in your version of Eclipse and create a Maven project." It also does not specify where in the pom.xml file to place dependencies. Under `<project>`? `<build>`? `<plugin>`?