# How to add Breeze to Scala project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-breeze

I am new to Scala and I am trying to import a Scala project into Eclipse IDE. I am getting this error:
`not found: object breeze.`

The line of the error is:
`import breeze.linalg._`

I have added the `breeze.jar` but the problem is not resolve. Can anybody help me how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breeze has **a lot** of dependencies, and so you're better off using SBT or Maven to manage dependencies for you. If you insist, I'd recommend following the directions for adding a Maven dependency directly to Eclipse (see, e.g., [How do I add a "maven dependency" in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164893/how-do-i-add-a-maven-dependency-in-eclipse))

And then add a dependency on breeze_2.11 version 0.11 (or _2.10 if you use scala 2.10)

Comment: Can you point me to some good tutorials to get started with Scala?

Comment: not really any better than Google could. You might look at Twitter's scala school, or things on the official Scala page, or the coursera class if that's your thing.