# Import project from github

Tags: android, eclipse, github

I found this animated circle bar and I want to add it to my project.

> https://github.com/jlmd/AnimatedCircleLoadingView

The problem is, I don't know where to add it and how to get it in my project.

I tried to add

```
<com.github.jlmd.animatedcircleloadingview.AnimatedCircleLoadingView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/circle_loading_view"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:background="@colors/orange"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
app:mainColor="@colors/orange"
app:secondaryColor="@colors/blue"
/>
```

on my  activity_main.xml
 but I guess it's not the only thing I have to do.

Any informations about how to use this code in my project will be appreciated.

If I import it to Eclipse I recieve this

*Error retrieving parent for item: **No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.**   styles.xml  /MainActivity/res/values    line 4  Android AAPT Problem*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't added the dependency for the Library.
To do that, you can refer to [this article.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164893/how-do-i-add-a-maven-dependency-in-eclipse)

The dependency you need to add is provided on the documentation for the Library (but it's for Android Studio, so you can use the above link to add it to Eclipse):

> Add dependency to your build.gradle
>
> compile 'com.github.jlmd:AnimatedCircleLoadingView:1.1.5@aar'

Comment: I'm still searching for a way to add repositories to my build.gradle and depencendy because there is no videos on youtube. If I want to search for  "how to add dependencies, repostory on eclipse", etc.  it gives me results for Android Studio. How and where can I find a tutorial? Please help me!

Comment: I'm using Eclipse

Comment: You can go through this article - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164893/how-do-i-add-a-maven-dependency-in-eclipse

Answer (score 3):

Add repository to your build.gradle

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven"
    }
}
```

Add dependency to your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.github.jlmd:AnimatedCircleLoadingView:1.1.5@aar'
```

Reference [AnimatedCircleLoadingView](https://github.com/jlmd/AnimatedCircleLoadingView#gradle-dependency)

Comment: The repository url hast to be in module gradle

Comment: @MuratK. Disagree to the "HAS TO BE". But i will agree if it is "CAN BE" or more specific if it is "RECOMMENDED TO BE". :-)