# Adding itextpdf libraries to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, itext

I seem to be going in circles trying to add the itextpdf libraries to my Eclipse. It seems that itext is available via github but I don't see the jar files for including in Eclipse as external libraries. On the other hand, it looks like it is available via the Maven repositories but with much searching, I cannot figure out how to include them in Eclipse. All I can find are instructions that involve editing pom.xml and/or settings.xml. Surely it is not really that complicated.

So my question is what do I use in the install new software panel as the site for itext or maven? Alternatively, where can I find the itext jar files to download? TIA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The iText source code is managed in [Github](https://github.com/itext). You can download the iText 7 binaries (the `.jar` files) in the `.zip` files in the [releases page](https://github.com/itext/itext7/releases) or the [developer's page](https://developers.itextpdf.com/downloads). There is a *Community* (opensource) version you can download freely.

---

If you are using Eclipse, I recommend you create a Maven project and add the dependency. There are some instructions at the [installation page](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java):

- Create a Maven project, using `File > New > Project ... > Maven Project`
- In the wizard, select `Create a simple project`to skip the selection of an archetype, define a *Group Id* and an *Artifact Id* and click on `Finish`.
- Add the *iText* dependency to the project using [the wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164893/how-do-i-add-a-maven-dependency-in-eclipse), or editing the `pom.xml` file.

After you define the dependency, Eclipse/Maven will download the dependencies (the `.jar` files).

---

If you edit the `pom.xml` you must add the iText dependency. The installation page mentions that you can add all the *Community* packages using the following snippet:

```
<!-- add all iText 7 Community modules -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.4</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have a project but now want to start adding reporting to it using itext. Can I add Maven to the existing project or am I creating a new project just to get the Maven repositories into Eclipse that can be used anywhere?

P.S. I have a dozen pom.xml files so how do I know which one to use?

Comment: If your project does not use Maven, you may create one based on your source code. -- Eclipse has a wizard that may help you. You can right click on your project and select `Configure > Convert to Maven Project`. You must answer some questions there. -- It may convert simple project. Complex projects may require more work,

Comment: I guess my Eclipse installation is missing something. I do no have that menu item under configure. I have 4 other conversion options but not that one.

Comment: Ummm... That depends on the plugins you have installed. I Just checked in my (old) Eclipse Neon (installed without many plugins) and the menu exists there. -- Try to install the m2e extension/plugins in your Eclipse.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thanks. FWIW, my Eclipse is Mars 2.

Comment: Probably, this may be an opportunity to upgrade your Eclipse  :) -- I just tested in the most recent Eclipse Oxygen 1a, and the menu is there.

Comment: I got it. I first installed m2e which gave me the maven conversion option. However, when done I still had no itextpdf. So I upgraded to Oxygen.1A which didn't really do much to help. However, I found an article that showed I needed to rebuild the index with the maven repositories. Then I was able to add the itext dependency. None of this went through the normal install software wizard. Seems like a flaw in the process to me. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Sorry. I did not mention it. -- Every time you manually change the `pom.xml` to change versions or include new dependencies, or when you checkout the project (e.g. from Github), you must right click the project and execute `Maven > Update project...` to download and update the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but I found the Artifactory repo here: https://repo.itextsupport.com/webapp/#/search/quick/eyJzZWFyY2giOiJxdWljayIsInF1ZXJ5IjoiY29tLml0ZXh0cGRmLnBkZmRlYnVnLnNpdGUtMi4wLjEuemlwIn0= 
I extracted the repo location and exact search term from the Eclipse Marketplace URL, which would not download because of the sun.security.validator.ValidatorException problem.  But I could download the zip file and installed in Eclipse- do: Help | Install New... | Add... | Archive... -- then navigate to the zip download and it will install that way.