# Java Eclipse/Maven, Hanging on Dependency Build for JAXB 4+ Hrs

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, dependencies

I've run into a big issue, and it's stalling my project that is due this weekend. Here are the details.

IDE: Eclipse/Maven
API: JAXB, an xml reader/writer API
Issue: Maven is hanging when building the dependency in pom.xml.

More Information: I copy and pasted the jar into a project folder "lib". Then moved the project over to the resource folder. After that, I used maven from eclipse (I think that's the embedded Maven), to add the dependency to the pom.xml. It's been over 4 hours now. I also stopped eclipse through Windows Task Manager. When eclipse started after that, it is continuing with the Maven dependency build, and will not finish.

It is step 5, in this stackoverflow thread. [How do I add a Maven dependency in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164893/how-do-i-add-a-maven-dependency-in-eclipse)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This has sucked a whole day out of actual coding; and turned into a configuration issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer, not that I think it will give you a complete answer, but as a way to try to get more useful information about your situation.

It would help if you provided more details about exactly what you're doing, and what exactly is happening.

Maven does not "build" dependencies, it downloads dependency artifacts from an artifact repository.

When you say that something is "hanging", that means that an operation starts and doesn't complete, as opposed to failing with an error message.  If what you're doing is truly "hanging", then it's important to be exactly clear on exactly what operation and point in the process it is hanging.

You then say that you copied the jar into a folder named "lib" and then "moved the project over to the resource folder".

By "the jar", do you mean the Maven artifact that you're trying to download, which you said was "hanging"?  What is the significance of this "lib" folder?  Is your build somehow referencing jars in that folder as additional dependencies, subverting the typical maven dependency process?  If so, how exactly are you doing this?

Next, what do you mean by "moved the project over to the resource folder"?

Consider all of this from an external perspective.  You have to give us enough information to understand exactly what problem you're having, and what you've done that isn't working.  So far, you haven't done that.