# ExpectedException with @Rule in junit test on eclipse IDE does not work

Tags: eclipse, junit, rules, expected-exception

I need to make a test in junit that passes if an exception is thrown, but fail time and again.

I read a bunch of questions and answers on the topic here in stackoverflow and on other sources. Eventually I came across this page, that explains the usage of Class [ExpectedException](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html#none()), by junit.org.

Since I could not get my own test working I copied their bare-bones example and it still did not work.

here is my code:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

class AssertExceptionTest {
    
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown= ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void throwsNothing() {
        // no exception expected, none thrown: passes.
    }

    @Test
    public void throwsExceptionWithSpecificType() {
        thrown.expect(NullPointerException.class);
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}
```

Citing from the page I mentioned above, the explanation goes "...***After specifiying the type of the expected exception your test is successful when such an exception is thrown and it fails if a different or no exception is thrown***...

Problem is that the test still fails, no matter what I do, and it fails because of what I am trying to verify: throwing NullPointerException.

I thought that maybe, because I am using junit 5, my test fails. However, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268446/junit-5-how-to-assert-an-exception-is-thrown) from stackoverflow suggests otherwise: the guy asking the question mentions he is using junit 5 in eclipse  the same way as in my code, successfully.

Technical details:
eclipse version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)
junit version: junit 5
working on Ubuntu, version: 18.04.2 LTS.

***Update***:
I used *assertThrows()*, and it worked for me. However, I am still puzzled over the reason I didn't succeed with the methods described above, which many people here suggest.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUnit 5 does not support JUnit 4 Rules out of the box.

To make your code working:

1. Add the following dependency (version might change over time, of course)

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-migrationsupport</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.2</version> 
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

2. Next, put `@EnableRuleMigrationSupport` on top of your test class.

That's it. See [this](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-rule-support) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Mensur Qulami ! I followed your instructions and it worked beutifully! I never had to use Maven before, so for anyone who will read this and know NOTHING about MAVEN, the explanation on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164893/how-do-i-add-a-maven-dependency-in-eclipse) helped me a lot, specifically Oded Breiner answer and cliff2310 comment to oded's answer