# Eclipse/Maven - can't update index and add new dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164893/how-do-i-add-a-maven-dependency-in-eclipse) about basic usage of Maven in Eclipse. First time I followed the instructions in the accepted answer it worked fine but now, when I try to do that again, it fails.

1. Rebuilding the index doesn't seem to work - it returns immediately (first time it took 15-20 minutes or so).
2. When I right-click on `Central` and switch between `Enable minimum index` and `Full index enabled` I get this error message:

[image: Error setting index details, Unable to set the index details due to the following error, no such file or directory]

3. When trying to add a dependency in the dependency view, it just finds stuff that is already in the workspace.

What I have done to remedy this:

- `Preferences -> Maven -> Download repository index updates on startup` - checked and unchecked
- Restarted Eclipse
- Deleted the `Nexus` directory specified in the error message
- Created an empty file `_di.cfs`. This lead to some error message about reading beyond EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Your Eclipse workspace is now corrupted.  Never modify those files directly.  Your best strategy at this point is to create a new workspace.

Accept the fact that building a full index from scratch takes a long time.  It's not clear to me what the value is of a full index vs. a minimum index.  I wouldn't bother with using a full index at this point.

Comment: The reason I switched index type was just in an attempt to fix my problem. Is minimum index the default?